# Creating a mouseover zoom or hover zoom in RShiny

Tags: shiny, hover, zooming, mouseover, shinyapps

I am building an app with RShiny that renders a pdf as a PNG image which is then shown via a call to imageOutput (If needed, the image can be rendered via a different output, such as plotOutput).

I would like the user to be able to mouse-over or hover over the image to show a larger, more zoomed in version or subset of that same image (Example below).

Is there a way to accomplish this in Shiny?

Thank you

[image: zoom_mouseover]

Comment: There are multiple [jquery plugins](https://www.learningjquery.com/2016/07/12-jquery-plugins-to-create-image-zoom-effect) for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an attempt based on [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_zoom_hover.asp):

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    uiOutput('image'),
    tags$style('div#image:hover {
                 transform: scale(1.5);
                 transform-origin: top left;
                }')
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$image <- renderUI({
      tags$img(src = 'https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlaci.jpg', width = 400)
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Please play around with `transform` and `transform-origin` to suit your needs.

Comment: I ended up using this from W3schools instead (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp), thanks for sending me in that direction

Comment: Sure, glad to have helped. Maybe add your answer to help future searchers.

Comment: @michael can you share an code example with your implementation, since iam trying to find the best solution for an related problem. greetings

Comment: Sorry @lucaskr. I was unable to find the code snippet I used

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into the same problem, since I wanted to have a jpg image in my shiny app with the hover zoom functionality.

Since not provided by [@michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620682/michael) I'm sharing a working example of a shiny app based on the [w3schools example](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_image_zoom.asp).

R code:

```
library(shiny)

# probably not necessary, but I didn't get the www path working any other way
addResourcePath("www", "www")

ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
        # add css code
        tags$style(HTML("
            * {box-sizing: border-box;}
            .img-zoom-container {
              position: relative;
            }
            .img-zoom-lens {
              position: absolute;
              border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
              width: 40px;
              height: 40px;
            }
            .img-zoom-result {
              border: 1px solid #d4d4d4;
              width: 300px;
              height: 300px;
            }
        "))
    ),
    # add html code (I guess that's also possible by using img()
    # and so on, as long as you add the class and id)
    tags$h1("Image Zoom"),
    tags$p("Mouse over the image:"),
    div(class = "img-zoom-container",
        tags$img(
          id = "myimage",
          src = "www/988b6dd1-72be-4095-a602-f0870116b9d6.jpg",
          # src = "https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_girl.jpg",
          width = "800"
          # ,
          # height = "240"
        ),
        div(id = "myresult", class = "img-zoom-result")
    ),
    tags$p("The image must be placed inside a container with relative positioning."),
    tags$p("The result can be put anywhere on the page, but must have the class name 'img-zoom-result'."),
    tags$p("Make sure both the image and the result have IDs. These IDs are used when a JavaScript initiates the zoom effect."),
    
    # Include your JavaScript functions and initialization script
    tags$script(src = "www/javascript.js")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    # Server-side functionality if needed
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Javascript code (save here: "www/javascript.js"):

```
function imageZoom(imgID, resultID) {
    var img, lens, result, cx, cy;
    img = document.getElementById(imgID);
    result = document.getElementById(resultID);
    /*create lens:*/
    lens = document.createElement("DIV");
    lens.setAttribute("class", "img-zoom-lens");
    /*insert lens:*/
    img.parentElement.insertBefore(lens, img);
    /*calculate the ratio between result DIV and lens:*/
    cx = result.offsetWidth / lens.offsetWidth;
    cy = result.offsetHeight / lens.offsetHeight;
    /*set background properties for the result DIV:*/
    result.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + img.src + "')";
    result.style.backgroundSize = (img.width * cx) + "px " + (img.height * cy) + "px";
    /*execute a function when someone moves the cursor over the image, or the lens:*/
    lens.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
    img.addEventListener("mousemove", moveLens);
    /*and also for touch screens:*/
    lens.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
    img.addEventListener("touchmove", moveLens);
    function moveLens(e) {
      var pos, x, y;
      /*prevent any other actions that may occur when moving over the image:*/
      e.preventDefault();
      /*get the cursor's x and y positions:*/
      pos = getCursorPos(e);
      /*calculate the position of the lens:*/
      x = pos.x - (lens.offsetWidth / 2);
      y = pos.y - (lens.offsetHeight / 2);
      /*prevent the lens from being positioned outside the image:*/
      if (x > img.width - lens.offsetWidth) {x = img.width - lens.offsetWidth;}
      if (x < 0) {x = 0;}
      if (y > img.height - lens.offsetHeight) {y = img.height - lens.offsetHeight;}
      if (y < 0) {y = 0;}
      /*set the position of the lens:*/
      lens.style.left = x + "px";
      lens.style.top = y + "px";
      /*display what the lens "sees":*/
      result.style.backgroundPosition = "-" + (x * cx) + "px -" + (y * cy) + "px";
    }
    function getCursorPos(e) {
      var a, x = 0, y = 0;
      e = e || window.event;
      /*get the x and y positions of the image:*/
      a = img.getBoundingClientRect();
      /*calculate the cursor's x and y coordinates, relative to the image:*/
      x = e.pageX - a.left;
      y = e.pageY - a.top;
      /*consider any page scrolling:*/
      x = x - window.pageXOffset;
      y = y - window.pageYOffset;
      return {x : x, y : y};
    }
  }

  imageZoom("myimage", "myresult");
```